# How to customise CRUD actions Fiori (BOPF created from CDS)?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, cds

In master-detail app i add BOPF from CDS to create, edit, delete items (odata). Its working fine, but how can i extend standard CRUD actions? For example, i want to send mail when creating or updating item.
Thats how i add BOPF in CDS:

```
// BOPF CRUD
@Metadata.allowExtensions: true

@ObjectModel:{
    modelCategory: #BUSINESS_OBJECT,
    compositionRoot: true,
    transactionalProcessingEnabled: true,
    createEnabled: true,
    updateEnabled: true,
    deleteEnabled: true,
    writeActivePersistence: 'ZGUT_TEST_UI5'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I create new determination in eclipse, then found generated class and redefine method "execute". In this method we can do enything to want.